# radar chart ERROR "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (6,) and (5,)"

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart

I get an error when running the line `ax.fill(angles, scores_interests, 'r', alpha=0.1)`

```
x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (6,) and (5,)
```

Goal: create a
radar chart showing two sets of score values
('skills' and 'interests') on the same radar chart

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Score values for skills and interests
skills = {
    'Statistics': 5,
    'Python': 5,
    'SQL': 5,
    'QLIK': 5,
    'Pipelines': 5
}

interests = {
    'Statistics': 5,
    'Python': 5,
    'SQL': 5,
    'QLIK': 5,
    'Pipelines': 5
}

# Skill and interest categories
categories = list(skills.keys())

# Scores for the two sets
scores_skills = list(skills.values())
scores_interests = list(interests.values())

# Number of categories
num_categories = len(categories)

# Create angles for the radar chart
angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num_categories, endpoint=False).tolist()
angles += angles[:1]  # To close the radar chart

# Plot the radar chart
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Plot the skill scores
ax.fill(angles, scores_skills, 'b', alpha=0.1)
ax.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(angles), labels=categories)
plt.title('Radar Chart - Skills vs. Interests')

# Plot the interest scores
ax.fill(angles, scores_interests, 'r', alpha=0.1)

# Add a legend
plt.legend(['Skills', 'Interests'], loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Removing `angles += angles[:1]` seems very localized. I'm voting to close the question to _typo / not reproducible_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line:

```
angles += angles[:1]  # To close the radar chart
```

Just remove it and it will work (see images below).

That line is adding a 0.0 to `angles` which is not needed and makes that the list of angles is larger than the list of information (`scores_skills` and `scores_interests`). All lists must be of the same size.

[image: img]

Here, there is another image with different values:

[image: img_2]